# Hello, Im a beginner! Im having a problem on how to stop the countdown that i made in javascript. Can you please help me

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Im having a problem on how to stop the countdown that i made in javascript. Can you please help me.
here is my code:

```
                 const setIN = setInterval(function () {
                countDown();
              }, 1000);
              const countDown = () => {
                const countDate = new Date('June 15, 2021 07:19:00').getTime();
                const now = new Date().getTime();
                const gap = countDate - now;

                //console.log(countDate, now, gap);

                const second = 1000;
                const minute = second * 60;
                const hour = minute * 60;
                const day = hour * 24;

                //   console.log(second, minute, hour, day);

                const daysRemain = Math.floor(gap / day);
                const hoursRemain = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
                const minutesRemain = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
                const secondsRemain = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

                //   console.log(daysRemain, hoursRemain, minutesRemain, secondsRemain);

                document.querySelector('.days').innerText = daysRemain;
                document.querySelector('.hours').innerText = hoursRemain;
                document.querySelector('.minutes').innerText = minutesRemain;
                document.querySelector('.seconds').innerText = secondsRemain;
              };
```

im a beginner. sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the gap between the two dates is smaller or equal to 0. If so, you can stop the interval with `clearInterval()`:

```js
const setIN = setInterval(function() {
  countDown();
}, 1000);
const countDown = () => {
  const countDate = new Date('June 15, 2021 07:19:00').getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const gap = countDate - now;
  if (gap <= 0) {
    alert("time is up!");
    clearInterval(setIN);
    return;
  }
  //console.log(countDate, now, gap);

  const second = 1000;
  const minute = second * 60;
  const hour = minute * 60;
  const day = hour * 24;

  //   console.log(second, minute, hour, day);

  const daysRemain = Math.floor(gap / day);
  const hoursRemain = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
  const minutesRemain = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
  const secondsRemain = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

  //   console.log(daysRemain, hoursRemain, minutesRemain, secondsRemain);

  document.querySelector('.days').innerText = daysRemain;
  document.querySelector('.hours').innerText = hoursRemain;
  document.querySelector('.minutes').innerText = minutesRemain;
  document.querySelector('.seconds').innerText = secondsRemain;
};
```

```html
<div class="days"></div>
<div class="hours"></div>
<div class="minutes"></div>
<div class="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help bro. it works. but stops at -1. i dont know why.

Comment: @Anojay I've updated my answer to include a `return`. If it helps, please consider accepting! :) [How do I accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Anojay Glad to help :)

Comment: realy helps me a lot! tnx. just a beginner. hope you understand. :D